# how to show number with comma separated in text box angular, getting incorrect thousand separator

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

how to show number with comma separated. like this 1,000.

```
<kendoTextBox ControlId="Amount" [ControlLabel]="'Amount*'" [maxLength]="100"
        [TextValue]="Amount"  (txtBoxchangeEvent)="onChangeAmount($event)" ></kendoTextBox>

onChangeAmount(e){
  this.Amount = e.TextValue.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

output -2,0,0,0,000

 expected op-2,000,000
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the DecimalPipe pipe.

You can find it pretty easy in the angular documentation.

Comment: i cant use pipe here. im looking for perfect thousand separator regex. 2,0,0,0,000 expected op-2,000,000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).